# Investigate why user has access to a folder

Tags: windows, security, network-share, file-permissions, debugging

How can I understand why a particular user has access to a particular shared folder?

Security tab of the folder contains a long list of groups groups and the user is not a direct member of any of those groups so there must be some intermediary groups involved.

Answer (score 1):

Well you didn't give any details about your environment, but assuming a Windows domain, why not Powershell?

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership someUser | Select Name
```

Now you have a list of all groups of which that user is a member. Of course that only applies to your AD domain, so it will not tell you if that user is a member of any local groups on a computer.

Also I notice you listed network-share as a tag of this question. If this a network share in question, be aware that there are two different kinds of permissions on a network share - share permissions and NTFS permissions. NTFS permissions have the final say, so configuring a network share as "Everyone - Full Control" on the network share permissions is pretty common, and then relying on NTFS permissions to actually grant or deny access appropriately.

Comment: I do get list of groups for which user is a member but none of those groups is granted access to my folder still I have the access. As I mentioned in the question there must be intermediary groups involved. I.e. `User`-->`Group1`-->`Group2`-->`Group3` and `Group3` has access to the folder.